# Restricting textfield to three numbers

Tags: javascript

I want to check my textField if there is more than three characters entered.

```
if(e.source.length > 3){       
    // I want only the first three numbers and other digits should be removed. 
}
```

I tried using `e.source.value.replace(RegularExpression,e.source.value(0,3))`

Comment: Not sure what you want.   Do you only want three numbers (and if so, are + and - allowed).   Do you only want 3 characters?   Do you only want the first three characters if more than 3 are entered?

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="text" maxlength="3" />
<textarea maxlength="3"></textarea>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7FLbw/), not JS required

Comment: +1 for no js, won't work for `<textarea>` though in older browsers, AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

you could use `var a = "something";  var b = a.slice(0,3);`

Answer (score 0):

Its simple:

```
var text = document.getElementById('textboxID');
if(text.value.length>3){
//do something
}
```